# Does socket.io-redis support redis clusters?

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

Can I use a redis cluster transparently (without writing any client side code for the redis cluster) with socket-io-redis instead of a single redis server as the default examples state? Unfortunately, there seems to be no official documentation on this.

Also, without a redis cluster, how many users can socket.io servers support with a single redis server as socket.io-redis backend?

**Update:**

Socket.io-redis allows specification of redis clients to use. May be some node_redis compatible redis client which also has support for redis clusters can be used? ioredis (the only other full featured/recommended client) has support for redis clusters but I am not sure if it's compatible with the node_redis client. Does anyone have some info on it or other possible solutions?

**Note:** I know Redis cloud provides scaling solution with a single endpoint paradigm but I need a cluster solution.

Answer (score 0):

The module [socket.io-ioredis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-ioredis) allows use of ioredis with socket.io. Ioredis can connect to a redis cluster. However, I have, so far, only used socket.io-ioredis with socket.io with a single node server and single redis instance and it's working okay in this configuration.